# Norm of $T^n$ a bounded linear operator in a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X\to X$ be a bounded linear operator on a Banach space $X$. Is it true that

$$\|T^n\|=\|T\|^n?$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\mathbb R^2$ and $$T=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right],$$ considered as a linear operator. Then, the operator norm of $T$ is $1$, but $T^2$ is the null matrix, so $\|T^2\|=0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not generally true.  As a counterexample, take $T:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ under the induced $1$-norm.  Define
$$
T = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$
We have 
$$
\|T^n\| = \left\|\pmatrix{1&n\\0&1}\right\| = n+1 \neq \|T\|^n
$$
However, we will always have the inequality $\|T\|^n \geq \|T^n\|$ by the sub-multiplicative property of induced norms.